# Auth0 - Unable to see/get login or signup page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, auth0, okta

I am trying to use Auth0 for the first time and referred sample code from here to create a Asp.net MVC sample application. https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-mvc-samples/tree/master/Quickstart/Sample

I have created the application and have set all the settings as mentioned on the Auth0 starter page as well as the guidelines mentioned here https://medium.com/@gnerva/auth0-and-asp-net-core-mvc-net-6-0-tutorial-ef3a082ae415.
I am using Visual Studio Dev tunnels to test but I am always getting a below error instead of seeing the login or signup page.

```
InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://<mydomain>-dev.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '2/21/2024 10:39:46 PM +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
```

I am not sure what could be an issue but would really love to get an insight to resolve an issue.

Thank you so much.

below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Metadata coming correctly from the domain url.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduced this error when filled appsettings with wrong domain.
[image]

So double check the Auth0 dashboard of the app domain.
[image]
if it is same as appsettings
[image]

It seems "-dev.auth0.com" is not a right format.

Comment: I am able to get metadata using the above domain. The domain is the same in appsettings and in the application setting. Added screenshot to the original post showing metadata,

Comment: @Sachin This issue may also happen by TLS errors. I suggest you use wireshark to observe the network traffic to see if there's any TLS handshake error.